# plotting 4th variable as color or density

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a LG laser pulse having orbital angular momentum. Equation depends upon 3 variables `r`, `theta`, and `z` in cylindrical coordinates and the field of laser pulse depends upon these 3 coordinates and rotates as it propagates in the medium.

To plot the field as color maap, I have created a 3D `meshgrid` using `r`, `theta`, and `z` coordinates but the resulting plot doesn't look like it's rotating. I am stuck and don't understand the problem.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

# Defined Parameters
p = 1  # The order of the Laguerre polynomial
m = 1 #The azimuthal order of the pulse
theta0 = 0
r0 = 20e-6
E0 = 1.22e+12 #V/m
k0 = 536625
r = np.linspace(0, 20e-6, 100)
theta = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
z = np.linspace(-3, 0, 100)
f = np.sqrt(np.math.factorial(p)/(np.math.factorial(m+p)))*((np.sqrt(2)*r/r0)**m)*(2*r**2/r0**2)*np.cos(m*(theta-theta0))
# Define the equation E = f(r, theta, z)
def equation(r, theta, z):
    return E0*f*np.exp(-r**2/r0**2)*np.cos(k0*z)

# Generate data for the plot

X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(r, theta, z)
E = equation(X, Y, Z)

# Create a 3D density plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Plot the density using a colormap
density_plot = ax.scatter(Z, Y, X, c=E, cmap='plasma', s=1)

# Add a colorbar to the plot
cbar = plt.colorbar(density_plot)
cbar.set_label('E Value')

# Set axis labels
ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot is something like this:

[image: Resulting pic]

However it should look something like this rotating with `r`, `theta`, and `z`.

[image: Expected outcome]

Comment: there's no theta term in your `equation` function even though you pass in `theta` as an argument

Comment: theta is there and defined in f in equation in the code

Comment: no, you use `theta` to define `f`, outside the equation. Then you pass `Y` into the `equation` function as the second argument, which then becomes `theta` inside the scope of the function. But that local `theta` is not used inside the function, so effectively, `Y` is not used

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

There are a few different things that you will need to change in order to fix your code. The main issue is that when you plot the data you use do not convert to cartesian coordinates. The `ax.scatter(...)` function takes positional arguments as `x,y,z` instead of `r,θ,z`. Additionally, your bounds for `θ` are wrong and a few lines of code need to be moved around to make it all work.

#### Step 1

The first thing you should do is move `f = np.sqrt(...)`  into the `def equation(...)` function. This is because the value of `f` changes with the value of `theta`, which is not constant inside of the function.

```
## Incorrect
f = np.sqrt(np.math.factorial(p)/(np.math.factorial(m+p)))*((np.sqrt(2)*r/r0)**m)*(2*r**2/r0**2)*np.cos(m*(theta-theta0))
def equation(r, theta, z):
    return E0*f*np.exp(-r**2/r0**2)*np.cos(k0*z)
```

```
## Correct
def equation(r, theta, z):
    f = np.sqrt(np.math.factorial(p)/(np.math.factorial(m+p)))*((np.sqrt(2)*r/r0)**m)*(2*r**2/r0**2)*np.cos(m*(theta-theta0))
    return E0*f*np.exp(-r**2/r0**2)*np.cos(k0*z)
```

Output after changes.
[image: move f variable inside of function]

#### Step 2

Convert your cylindrical coordinate values to cartesian coordinates! This makes it possible for `ax.scatter(...)` to appropriately plot your data.

```
## Incorrect
X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(r, theta, z)
E = equation(X, Y, Z)

# Create a 3D density plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Plot the density using a colormap
density_plot = ax.scatter(Z, Y, X, c=E, cmap='plasma', s=1)
```

```
## Correct
X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(r, theta, z)
E = equation(X, Y, Z)

xs = X*np.cos(Y)
ys = X*np.sin(Y)
zs = Z

# Create a 3D density plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Plot the density using a colormap
density_plot = ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, c=E, cmap='plasma', s=1)
```

Output after changes.
[image: converted coordinates]

#### Step 3

Change the bounds on `θ` to create a full cylinder instead of just a half (`2π` instead of `π`).

```
## Incorrect
theta = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
```

```
## Correct
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
```

Output after changes.
[image: theta up to two pi]

## Final Product

[image: what the figure should be]

Even after solving the plotting issues, your output will not look like the image above. This is because your equations used to calculate `E` are incorrect. Here is some code that I made in an attempt to fix the errors. I also changed the tolerance level on `E` so that only extreme values are plotted and it is easier to see the spirals. Please see page 222 of [Laser Resonators and Beam Propagation](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b106789) by Hodgson and Weber for a complete description of the equations used.

#### Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import time

start = time.perf_counter()

# Defined Parameters
ps = 1  # The order of the Laguerre polynomial
ms = 1 #The azimuthal order of the pulse
r0s = 1
z = np.linspace(-5, 5, 20)
x = np.linspace(-1.5,1.5,15)
y = np.linspace(-1.5,1.5,15)

a,b = np.meshgrid(x,y)

rs = np.sqrt(a**2 + b**2)
thetas = np.arctan2(a,b)
fs = np.sqrt( (2 * np.math.factorial(ps)) / (np.pi * np.math.factorial(ps+ms)))

# Define the equation E = f(r, theta, z)
def equation(r, theta, z, m, r0, f):
    multiplier = (1 / r0) * np.exp(-(r**2) / (r0**2)) * (((r * np.sqrt(2)) / r0)**m)
    laguerre1 = (m+1) - ((2 * (r**2)) / (r0**2))
    return f*multiplier*laguerre1* (np.cos(z+theta))

# Generate data for the plot
X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(rs, thetas, z)
E = equation(X, Y, Z, ms, r0s, fs)

xs = (X*np.cos(Y))[abs(E)>0.25]
ys = (X*np.sin(Y))[abs(E)>0.25]
zs = Z[abs(E)>0.25]

# Create a 3D density plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Plot the density using a colormap
density_plot = ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, c=E[abs(E)>0.25], cmap='plasma', s=1)

# Add a colorbar to the plot
cbar = plt.colorbar(density_plot)
cbar.set_label('E Value')

# Set axis labels
ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

# Show the plot
plt.show()

end = time.perf_counter()

print("\nTotal runtime:", (end-start), "s")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the equation given above by [trent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19127570/trent), the comprehension of the function is clearer by viewing cylindrical coordinate surfaces.  Also note that along z = -t, the function is only dependent on r. This is illustrated in the Matplotlib figure below:

[image: Four surface plots]

The lower right surface in this figure is a left-handed helicoid.  The following code for this figure uses [S3Dlib](https://s3dlib.org/), a Matplotlib third party package.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import s3dlib.surface as s3d

ps, ms, r0s = 1,1,1
fs = np.sqrt( (2 * np.math.factorial(ps)) / (np.pi * np.math.factorial(ps+ms)))

def equation(r, theta, z, m, r0, f):
    multiplier = (1 / r0) * np.exp(-(r**2) / (r0**2)) * (((r * np.sqrt(2)) / r0)**m)
    laguerre1 = (m+1) - ((2 * (r**2)) / (r0**2))
    return f*multiplier*laguerre1* (np.cos(z+theta))

# ................................
E = lambda rtz : equation(rtz[0], rtz[1], rtz[2], ms, r0s, fs)
Exyz = lambda xyz : E(s3d.CylindricalSurface.coor_convert(xyz))
clipXYZ = lambda xyz : np.abs(Exyz(xyz))>0.25 

def helix(rtz,isPosR=True) :     # 0 < t < 2pi
    r,t,z = rtz
    R = r if isPosR else -r
    T = 2*t - 2*np.pi            # start at -2pi
    return R,T,-T                # z = -theta

# -------------------------------------------------------------------
for i,z in enumerate([-1,-.33,0.33,1]) :
    s = s3d.PolarSurface.grid(40,80).domain(1.5,z*2*np.pi)
    s.map_cmap_from_op( E, 'plasma' )
    disks = s if i==0 else s+disks

cyldr = s3d.CylindricalSurface.grid(40,80,'dv').domain(1.5,-2*np.pi)
cyldr.map_cmap_from_op( E, 'plasma' )

eSurf = s3d.PlanarSurface(7).domain(3,3)
eSurf.map_geom_from_op( lambda xyz : (xyz[0], xyz[1], Exyz(xyz))  )
eSurf.map_cmap_from_op( lambda xyz : xyz[2], 'plasma' ).shade()

h1 = s3d.PolarSurface.grid(60,100, 'x').domain(1.5)
h1.map_geom_from_op( helix )
h2 = s3d.PolarSurface.grid(60,100, 'x').domain(1.5)
h2.map_geom_from_op( lambda rtz : helix(rtz,False) )
helicoid = (h1+h2).map_cmap_from_op( Exyz, 'plasma' ).shade(.5)
# helicoid.clip(clipXYZ)

# -------------------------------------------------------------------
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
for i,[surface,title] in \
        enumerate([ [disks,'polar'],[cyldr,'cylindrical'],
        [eSurf,r'E(r,$\theta$,0)'],[helicoid,r'$\theta$ = -z'] ]) :
    ax = fig.add_subplot(221+i, projection='3d')
    ax.set(xlabel='X',ylabel='Y',zlabel='E' if i==2 else 'Z',
        xticks=(-1.5,0,1.5),yticks=(-1.5,0,1.5))
    s3d.auto_scale(ax,surface)
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.add_collection3d(surface)

fig.tight_layout(pad=2)
plt.show()
```

By retaining only the extreme values of the helicoid surface (using the surface `clip` method with the `clipXYZ` expression), the spiral form is visualized:

[image: Helicoid surface]

The code section to create the above figure of this surface is:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
s3d.auto_scale(ax,helicoid)
ax.set(xlabel='X',ylabel='Y',zlabel='Z',title='|E| > 0.25')
cbar = plt.colorbar(helicoid.cBar_ScalarMappable, ax=ax,  shrink=0.8, label='E value' )
ax.add_collection3d(helicoid)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Considering the request that it 'should look' like the 3D example, the visualization should be surfaces of constant E whereas the above are surfaces of E for theta = -z.  Since E is a function of r, theta and z, surface coordinates of E=c need be determined, where c is constant.  These may be obtained using marching cubes, available at
[skimage](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.marching_cubes). Marching cubes algorithm determines coordinates where the function, f, is zero in a specified domain.  For this case, the function is simply, f(x,y,z) = E(x,y,z) - c.  Using this and the previously defined code functions, the following figure was created:

[image: coils]

where the code is:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.measure import marching_cubes_lewiner
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import s3dlib.surface as s3d

ps, ms, r0s = 1,1,1
fs = np.sqrt( (2 * np.math.factorial(ps)) / (np.pi * np.math.factorial(ps+ms)))

def equation(r, theta, z, m, r0, f):
    multiplier = (1 / r0) * np.exp(-(r**2) / (r0**2)) * (((r * np.sqrt(2)) / r0)**m)
    laguerre1 = (m+1) - ((2 * (r**2)) / (r0**2))
    return f*multiplier*laguerre1* (np.cos(z+theta))

# ................................
E = lambda rtz : equation(rtz[0], rtz[1], rtz[2], ms, r0s, fs)
Exyz = lambda xyz : E(s3d.CylindricalSurface.coor_convert(xyz))

def getVF(value) :
    N = 81
    n, XYd, Zd  = N*1j, 2, 2*np.pi  # number pts, +-domains
    ABC = np.mgrid[-XYd:XYd:n, -XYd:XYd:n, -Zd:Zd:n]
    xyz = np.reshape(ABC,(3,-1))
    vol = Exyz(xyz)-value                     # f(xyz) = 0
    vol = np.reshape(vol,(N,N,N))
    spacing = 2*np.array([XYd,XYd,Zd])/(N-1)  # scale cube
    verts, faces, norm, vals = marching_cubes_lewiner(vol, 0.001, spacing)
    verts = np.subtract(verts,[XYd,XYd,Zd])   # offset cube
    return [verts,faces]

surface1 = s3d.Surface3DCollection( *getVF(0.25), color='orange').evert()
surface2 = s3d.Surface3DCollection( *getVF(-.25), color='blueviolet')
surface = surface1+surface2

fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
s3d.auto_scale(ax,surface)
ax.set(xlabel='X',ylabel='Y',zlabel='phase')
ax.add_collection3d(surface.shade(ax=ax).hilite(.5,focus=2))

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

where the `getVF` method has been added to compute the vertices and faces using marching cubes.  Whereas the result 'looks like' the example, the accuracy of the `equation' function is left to the understanding of the laser expert.

Comment: Both the above codes gives error always